# allocating an array inside a c function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to allocate and initialize an array inside a function, but I can't seem to fetch the values after returning.

This was my last almost-working attempt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int func(int **thing);

int main() {

 int *thing;

 func(&thing);

 printf("%d %d", thing[0], thing[1]);
}

int func(int **thing) {

 *thing = calloc(2, sizeof(int));

 *thing[0] = 1;
 *thing[1] = 2; 

 printf("func - %d %d \n", *thing[0], *thing[1]);
}
```

but the values printed outside the function are 1 and 0. 
There are lots of documentation on pointers out there, but I haven't found this specific case covered. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: maybe there's a problem due to operator precedence? I'd try replacing all the "*thing[x]" with "(*thing)[x]".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than passing a pointer-to-pointer, you may find it easier to return the newly allocated array from your function:

```
int *func();

int main() {

 int *thing;

 thing = func();

 printf("%d %d", thing[0], thing[1]);
}

int *func() {

 int *thing;

 thing = calloc(2, sizeof(int));

 thing[0] = 1;
 thing[1] = 2; 

 printf("func - %d %d \n", thing[0], thing[1]);

 return thing;
}
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because of this:

```
*thing[0]
```

Due to the precedence of operators, you should use:

```
(*thing)[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

The precedence of `*` and `[]` are such that your assignments mean `*(thing[0])`.  You need to explicitly parenthesize like `(*thing)[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `func()`, `*thing[n]` is equivalent to `*(thing[n])`, i.e. `*(*(thing + n))`, i.e. array indexing takes precedence over dereferencing.  You need to assign using `(*thing)[n]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` has higher precedence than derefferensing. Use explicit paranthesis : `(*thing)[0] = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

After using `()` for the right precedence, do not forget to change `*thing = calloc(2, sizeof(int));` to `thing = calloc(2, sizeof(*int));` and to allocate memory for `thing` elements, since its elements are pointers to integers.