# Initialize multiple arrays in function C programming

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, initialization

I am trying to write a function in C to initialize multiple double type arrays, with different sizes. The array size should be given in the function and the array values are assigned through previously defined functions and values.
The functions are to be set as void, since I should use them many times later at different places. Here is a version of the code which does not give reasonable results. Thanks for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//interpolation, source code from internet

int findCrossOver(double arr[], int low, int high, double x)
{
  // Base cases
  if (arr[high] <= x) // x is greater than all    
    return high;
  if (arr[low] > x)  // x is smaller than all
    return low;

  // Find the middle point
  int mid = (low + high)/2;  /* low + (high - low)/2 */

  /* If x is same as middle element, then return mid */
  if (arr[mid] <= x && arr[mid+1] > x)
    return mid;

  /* If x is greater than arr[mid], then either arr[mid + 1]
    is ceiling of x or ceiling lies in arr[mid+1...high] */
  if(arr[mid] < x)
      return findCrossOver(arr, mid+1, high, x);

  return findCrossOver(arr, low, mid-1, x);
}

void interp1(double xp[], double yp[], int xyplen, double x[], int xlen,double* y)
{
int index;
int i;
for (i=0; i<xlen; i++)
{
    index = findCrossOver(xp, 0, xyplen-1, x[i]);
    if(x[i] > xp[xyplen-1])
    {
        index--;
    }
    y[i] = ((x[i]-xp[index])*(yp[index+1]-yp[index]))/(xp[index+1]-xp[index]) + yp[index];
}
}

void fpr(double step, double* oldVal, double* xp, double* yp, double* x)
{
   int i;
   int xyplen = 5; //array sizes through many calculations inside the function
   int xylen = 10;  

   for(i=0; i<xyplen; i++)
   {
        xp[i] = i+1;
        yp[i] = 2*xp[i];
        printf("%f\n", xp [i]);
   }
    for (i=0; i<xylen; i++)
    {
        x[i] = i+0.5;
    }
   interp1(xp, yp, xyplen, x, xylen,oldVal);
}


int main()
{
    double *someVal=malloc(sizeof(double));
    double *yp=malloc(sizeof(double));
    double *xp=malloc(sizeof(double));
    double *x=malloc(sizeof(double));
    fpr(1.1,someVal, xp, yp, x); 
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(xp)/sizeof(xp[0]));
    int i;
    printf("Input Data\n");
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
    printf("(%.1f, %.1f)\t", xp[i], yp[i]);
    }
    printf("Interpolated Data\n");
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
    printf("(%.1f, %.1f)\t",x[i],someVal[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output (due to the printf commands):

```
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
5.000000
0
Input Data
(-14.5, 0.5)    (-22.0, -7.0)   (90.5, -14.5)   (653.0, -22.0)  (89.5, 90.5)
Interpolated Data
(90.5, -3.5)    (653.0, -2.5)   (89.5, 0.5) (-9.1, -7.0)    (4.5, -14.5)    (5.5, -22.0)    (6.5, 90.5) (7.5, 653.0)    (8.5, 89.5) (9.5, -9.1)
```

As you see the sizeof is just giving the first element address and output in main is not as expected.

Comment: There must be many duplicates of this, but the short answer is that when you pass an array to a function it *decays* to a pointer, so when you do `sizeof` on the function argument you get the size of the pointer and not the array it points to. Not that you have array anyway, you only have pointers to a ***single value***.

Answer (score 0):

> to initialize multiple double type arrays, with different sizes.

There are no arrays in the code you show, but just pointers to memory.

`sizeof(xp)` returns the size of the pointer `xp`, always, no matter to how much memory the pointer points.

This line

```
double *xp=malloc(sizeof(double));
```

defines `xp` as pointer to `double` and intialises it pointing to memory for storing exactly **one** double.

Same for `someVal`, `yp` and `x`.

By using indexing this memory beyond index `0` the code  invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I tried something like :  `void fpr(double step, double* oldVal, double* xp, double* yp, double* x)
{
    .....
    x=malloc(sizeof(double) * xylen);
//
   interp1(xp, yp, xyplen, x, xylen,oldVal);
}
`  with defining `double *x;` like in the main. although it works when pointers are global

Comment: @MRM: On how to allocate an array inside a function you moght like to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4179273/694576

Comment: basically I just want to have local arrays (in main) which are just defined once with the function initialize() and then used in main and other functions. I hope I have said it clearly. And the other thing is I have more than one array to return.

Comment: @MDM: Then do the call to `malloc()`, as you showed in your comment above, in `main()` and not in `fpr()`. And do it for each "array" you need, that is allocate as much memory as you need to each of the four pointers.

Comment: So there is a confusion here. The problem here is that array sizes are first given inside `fpr()` and then the array is allocated through that size. This is the idea. My question is, how I can do `malloc()` without knowing the size in main.

Comment: @MRM: Allocate the memory in `fpr()` (assuming you know the required size in `fpr()`) , but do it as explained in the answers given to the question linked in my 1st comment to this answer.

Comment: @MRM: The only difference to the what I linked is that in your case you need to pass up to the caller the sizes of the memory allocated as well.

Answer (score 0):

xp and yp are pointers to double in your code, not arrays.

use something like:

```
double *xp = malloc(sizeof(double) * num_of_elements0);
double *yp = malloc(sizeof(double) * num_of_elements1);
```

and **ALWAYS** check for null pointers.

```
if(xp != NULL && yp != NULL)
{
    /* Your code here */
}
```

I don't understand how do you want to initialize your arrays. Random numbers? Zeroes?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use `malloc(sizeof(double) * num_of_elements0)` because the num_elements (or the size) is to be defined inside the initialize function. I just need a function which gets many  unknown sized arrays and defines their size and elements. I just couldn't figure it out with arrays, so I started using pointers.

Comment: Then you could have a look at calloc().
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm